# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message '__HALT_COMPILER(); must be declared in a phar'

Tags: php, geoip, phar

I'm porting over some code from an older site to a newer one on the same domain, and I'm having an odd issue with some geo tracking code (GeoIP2) that uses a .phar archive to work. I keep getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message '__HALT_COMPILER(); must be declared in a phar'
```

The code traces to this:

```
<?php
if (class_exists('Phar')) {
Phar::mapPhar('geoip2.phar');
require 'phar://' . __FILE__ . '/phar-stub.php';
}
__HALT_COMPILER(); ?>
```

Of which the *Phar::mapPhar('geoip2.phar');* line is the one referenced in the error.

I have this tied into a form to determine submitter's geographical location. What is very odd, is that this form will work about every five minutes. But any more submissions than one per five minutes and I don't have any luck.

How can I tackle this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

xcache still has an issue with phar.
disable xcache in via your php ini